# Unable to recognise this code/work with DecoNetwork

Tags: html, liquid

this is my first post, and I'm currently having some difficulty with the custom HTML templates within DecoNetwork, would really appreciate some advice, please!

The DecoNetwork e-commerce sites are predominantly built using a drag and drop editor, but there are also custom HTML and custom CSS templates where you can override settings with your own code.

DecoNetwork seems to also use Liquid (according to their support pages), but I'm not sure if this is what is used in the <[{"snippet":}]> code below as it doesn't seem to follow the usual process of Liquid? As well as this, are these snippets of code locked down, or are they able to be manipulated?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wf-loading">
  <head>
<[{"snippet":"system_style_sheets"}]>
<[{"snippet":"system_head_js"}]>
  <title><[{"snippet":"title"}]></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <[{"snippet":"system_head_meta_tags"}]>
<[{"snippet":"favicon"}]>
  </head>
  <body class="dn-site">
    <header>
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction of whether I've got the right language here that will help with getting my head around this platform.

Many thanks